# What is the opposite of space to scroll up?

Tags: macos, web-browsing

What is the key that scrolls the page up in a web browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox), that is the opposite of using the spacebar, which scrolls down?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Shift-Space

Space goes down a page, and Shift-Space is the opposite, scrolling *up* one page.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the Page Up and Page Down keys.